# Are there any Star Trek locations that are not orbiting any stars, planets, etc?

Tags: star-trek

Most of the time in various ST series, they are traveling to planets or at least star systems to locations there. Certainly there are space stations and the like, but these all appear to be orbiting stars or planets. Are there any locations in Star Trek that are visited regularly but are not specifically part of a star system?

EDIT: It seems that the difficulty of this question lies in the definition of "regularly". My original intention was indeed "regularly visited on screen, perhaps more than 3 times in 3 separate episodic arcs", but it seems that there is practically no location that fits this (with the exception of like...Earth or Vulcan and the like). As such, I have accepted the answer that has stations visited more than once.

Comment: And if there are, how do they find them?!?

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_planet - The Founders homeworld was a 'Rogue Planet'. It gets visited several times.

Comment: K-7 (TOS: The Trouble with Tribbles) didn't seem to be associated with any star system, despite mention of Sherman's Planet. Also, so far as I can recall, the Bajoran wormhole, despite proximity to Bajor wasn't explicitly *in* the Bajoran star system.

Comment: I presume visited regularly on screen? For example the buoys in the neutral zone are mentioned, not visited on screen, but somebody must do maintenance on them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it just popped up here yesterday: [Deep Space Station K-7](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_Station_K-7), the one from TOS "The Trouble with Tribbles" is not located in orbit around a planet or star.  I think the same applies to most of the "Deep Space" stations, though I don't know how many of them (other than K-7 and, obviously DS9) actually appeared.

[image: The Enterprise departs Deep Space Station K-7 in the star-flecked blackness of interstellar space]

There's also [Starbase 375](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starbase_375) where the Federation fleet massed before attacking to retake DS9.

[image: The Federation fleet departs Starbase 375]

Comment: Actually any number of research stations are also located at a distance from any potentially inhabitable worlds/star systems.

Comment: and the "Argus" array (TNG: The Nth Degree)

Comment: I don't recall the Bajoran wormhole being actually *in* the Bajoran star system despite proximity to Bajor.

Comment: The wormhole is well inside the [Bajoran system](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran_system).

Comment: K7 is only visited twice in canon.

Comment: @DoscoJones All the more reason to leaveDS9 out of the list.

Comment: @Valorum Good point.  And Starbase 375 only appears in 4 episodes of DS9.  The problem is, other than major planets, and DS9, there are hardly any locations at all that could be considered to be "regularly" visited in canon.  TOS was famously a "wagon train to the stars" and hardly visited anywhere twice.  TNG wasn't much better, and VOY was probably worse.  I tried to find locations at least visited more than once.

Comment: @DavidW - Four times barely meets the requirements for "regular". Once or twice certainly does not.

Comment: @Valorum I think I read the question differently than you did.  I read "visited regularly" as applying to traffic _in general_, which a Starbase or other major Federation outpost certainly would be, not as requiring that the name ship of a series show up there several times a season.

Comment: You'd have a hard time proving K7 doesn't orbit a star.  There's no reason to think that.  Star Trek very rarely shows the system star.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify what "regular" means. It seems that there would be no locations that fit my criteria if the requirement were "more than twice".

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't "visited regularly" but the Mutara Nebula (converted to the unstable Genesis planet and its star, *Wrath of Khan*) was, well, a nebula, which tend to be well separated from stars that aren't forming within them.

Comment: As you say, not visited regularly.

Comment: Interesting nonetheless and at least tangentially related. Upvoted.